# How to use javascript in a HTML document to create a simple cost calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner when it comes to HTML coding. I am trying to complete an assignment for an online computer course. I have emailed my professor, but he has not been much help with this assignment. I must create a simple cost calculator that will allow a user to add quantity and price per item for up to three items. After an onclick button is pressed the total price should be displayed. I had a similar assignment last week and was able to complete the coding and design on my own. I cant figure this one out. This is the code that I have so far.

```
<html>
    <head> <title> Name </title>
          <br/> <br/>
 <h2> <p style="text-indent: 22em;"> <FONT SIZE="7" <center> Easy Cost Calculator</center> </FONT SIZE>  </h2> 
      <style type="text/css">
        body {background-color:light blue;
              color: blue;
              font-family: rockwell;
              }
           </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <body style="background:#006400">
    <form> <br/> 
    <center> <table border="2" cellpadding="25" cellspacing="25" bgcolor=lightgreen>
          <tr> 
           <th> # of Items </th> 
           <th> Cost Per Item</th>
           <th> Item Total</th> </tr>
          <tr> <td>  <input type="text" name="quantity1" size="20"> </td><td>  <input type="text" name="cost per item1" size="20"> </td><td>  <input type="text" name="item total1" readonly> </td> </tr>
          <tr> <td> <input type="text" name="quantity2" size="20"> </td> <td> <input type="text" name="cost per item2" size="20"> </td> <td> <input type="text" name="item total2" readonly> </td> </tr>
          <tr> <td> <input type="text" name="quantity3" size="20"> </td> <td> <input type="text" name="cost per item3" size="20"></td> <td> <input type="text" name="item total3" readonly> </td> </tr> 
          <tr> <center> <td> <input type="text" name="Total" readonly>      </td>  <td> <input type="button" value="Calculate Total" onclick='
         var q1 = document.forms[0].quantity1.value;
         var q2= document.forms[0].quantity2.value;
         var q3= document.forms[0].quantity3.value;
         var cpi1 = document.forms[0]. cost per item1.value;
         var cpi2= document.forms[0]. cost per item2.value;
         var cpi3= document.forms[0]. cost per item3.value;
         var st11= q1*cpi1;
         document.forms[0].item total1.value= st11;
             var st2= q2*cpi2;
         document.forms[0].item total2.value= st2;
         var st3= q3*cpi3;
         document.forms[0]. item total3.value= st3;
         var tc =st11+st2+st3 ;
     document.forms[0].total.value= tc;
     '>
     </button> </center> </td>  </tr>
     </table>
     <br/> <br/>

        </center>  
  </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you expand, what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: The only real issue you're having, is that names can't have spaces in them, and they are case-sensitive, you should be able to figure out the rest

Comment: You can reference JavaScript by including `<script> Code Here </script>` in your code.

Comment: You have *a lot* of errors. Your browser's console will help you debug, but you're using deprecated and obsolete tags, you have elements in the wrong places, not to mention lots of syntax errors.

Comment: Just a little tip. For your `onclick`, instead of having all of that JavaScript hardcoded, create a simple function that you can call.

Comment: And you'd do that by using proper names -> http://jsfiddle.net/aamwzxh1/1/ As the others are saying, it's all totally invalid and obsolete, and once you get it working you should really read up on current standards etc.

Comment: Thank y'all for your comments! I have tried to fix it. I used your suggestions and tips. I am getting frustrated and I am about to just turn in what I have.

Comment: Did you see @adeneo's link?  jsfiddle.net/aamwzxh1/1 that seemed pretty helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few problems here:

- your HTML is formatted incorrectly (you have `h2`, `p`, and `br` tags in the `<head>`, display tags **only go within your `<body>` tags** (you also have two opening `<body>` tags)
- you shouldn't use spaces in name attributes (e.g. `document.forms[0].item total2.value= st2;`) as it will make them difficult to reference with javascript, replace with an underscore or just remove the spaces
- you are jamming a ton of javascript in an inline event handler which is a mistake, it should all be moved to its own `<script>` tag

Start off by giving your button an `id` attribute so you can access it more easily with Javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate Total" id="total" />
```

Then, before your closing `</body>` tag, add a new `<script>` tag and get a handle to your button and move all of your inline logic into an `onclick` event handler:

```
// get a handle to your button by referencing its id attribute
var button = document.getElementById('total');
// programmatically add your click handler
button.onclick = function(){
   var q1 = document.forms[0].quantity1.value;
   var q2= document.forms[0].quantity2.value;
   var q3= document.forms[0].quantity3.value;
   var cpi1 = document.forms[0].costperitem1.value;
   var cpi2= document.forms[0].costperitem2.value;
   var cpi3= document.forms[0].costperitem3.value;
   var st11= q1*cpi1;
   document.forms[0].itemtotal1.value= st11;
   var st2= q2*cpi2;
   document.forms[0].itemtotal2.value= st2;
   var st3= q3*cpi3;
   document.forms[0].itemtotal3.value= st3;
   var tc =st11+st2+st3 ;
   document.forms[0].total.value= tc;
}
```

There are still many improvements that could be made here, but that should be enough to get you started

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, I don't want to give you the entire answer, but this should get you started.

- You will notice that you can access your `JavaScript` by referencing the `id`
- If you keep your JavaScript in the same file, then you will need to place it inside of the `<script></script>` tags. Otherwise, you can reference it by creating a separate JavaScript file. For example: `<script src="JavaScriptFile.js"></script>` This will be placed inside of your `<head></head>` tags.

In your **HTML**, you want to do the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate Total" id="calculations">
```

Your **JavaScript** should look like the following:

```
document.getElementById('calculations').onclick = function() {
    var q1 = document.forms[0].quantity1.value;
    var q2 = document.forms[0].quantity2.value;
    var q3 = document.forms[0].quantity3.value;
    var cpi1 = document.forms[0].cost1.value;
    var cpi2 = document.forms[0].cost2.value;
    var cpi3 = document.forms[0].cost3.value;
    var st11 = q1 * cpi1;
    document.forms[0].total1.value = st11;
    var st2 = q2 * cpi2;
    document.forms[0].total2.value = st2;
    var st3 = q3 * cpi3;
    document.forms[0].total3.value = st3;
    var tc = st11 + st2 + st3;
    document.forms[0].total.value = tc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use the `id` attribute for JavaScript over the `name` attribute. You can have both if you want, but it is much more easier to use `getElementById` (IMO). Note that `id` attributes **must** be unique.

```
<input type="text" id="costPerItem1" name="cost per item1" size="20">
<input type="text" id="costPerItem2" name="cost per item2" size="20">
...
```

Second, I'd be very surprise if your JavaScript will work, but regardless, it is better practice to move your javascript into a `<script>` tag, and make a function that you can reference in your HTML. You can also use `document.getElementById("the_element_id");` to reference your input tags in your javascript. So every element that you need to reference in JavaScript, add an `id` attribute to it!

Common practice is to place `<script>` tags at the bottom of your HTML file, but still within the `</html>` tag.

```
<script>
var onClick = function(event) {
     var q1 = document.getElemenById('quantity1').value;
     var q2 = document.getElemenById('quantity2').value;
     var q3 = document.getElemenById('quantity3').value;  
     //var q1 = document.forms[0].quantity1.value;
     //var q2= document.forms[0].quantity2.value;
     //var q3= document.forms[0].quantity3.value;

     var cpi1 = document.getElementById('costPerItem1').value;
     var cpi2 = document.getElementById('costPerItem2').value;
     var cpi3 = document.getElementById('costPerItem3').value;

     //this is invalid javascript because of the whitespace.
     //var cpi1 = document.forms[0]. cost per item1.value;
     //var cpi2= document.forms[0]. cost per item2.value;
     //var cpi3= document.forms[0]. cost per item3.value;

     var st11= q1*cpi1;

     //this is also invalid javascript because of the whitespaces "item total"

     document.getElementById('itemTotal1').value = st11;
     //document.forms[0].item total1.value= st11;

     var st2= q2*cpi2;

     document.getElementById('itemTotal2').value = st2;
     //document.forms[0].item total2.value= st2;

     var st3= q3*cpi3;

     document.getElementById('itemTotal3').value = st3;
     //document.forms[0]. item total3.value= st3;

     var tc = st11 + st2 + st3;

     //this is valid javascript, but to be consistent, and in case
     //you ever add more forms in the same page...
     //document.forms[0].total.value= tc;
     document.getElementById('total').value = tc;
};
</script>
```

Now your HTML...

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate Total" onclick="onClick(event)" />
```

Third, your HTML structure is not right. A typical HTML structure looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- your content --->
    </body>
</html>
```

the `<head>` tag is a tag for all metadata related information about your website. But nothing related to your actual content. So `<head>` tags should only contain tags such as `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<title>`, etc.

The `<body>` tag is the place for your actual content. You shouldn't have more than 1 `<head>` or `<body>` tag.

```
<h2> <p style="text-indent: 22em;"> <span style="text-align:center;font-size:7px"> Easy Cost Calculator</span>  </h2>
```

Should be in your body. Also notice I changed `<center>` tag and the `<FONT SIZE>` tag into a single `<span style="text-align:center;font-size:7px;">` tag.

And finally...

```
<body>
 <body style="background:#006400">
```

should simply be

```
<body style="background:#006400">
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an api to make a calculator automatically, just put the api inside script tag. `<script src="https://calculatorapi.netlify.app/api.js"></script>` I created this api to help more people build their own web apps.
If you want to style your calculator just do:

```
<style>

<!--To result input-->

input[type="text"] {

<!--Your style-->

}

<!-- To Calculator buttons e.g: 1,2,3 -->

input[type="buttons"] {

<!-- Your style -->

}
</style>
```